# Can this be simplified even further?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current

Wondering if this could be simplified even further. Feels like I can do more with the 1000 ohm and the 2000 ohm resistors on the righthand side.

[image]

Comment: Two comments: 1) This is almost unreadable to me, what software has been used to produce it? Why does it fill up everything with dots? (and it's sideways). 2) It can be simplified to nothing at all since no nodes or currents are of interest. For example, if you care about the current through the 1k resistor, it can not be merged with the 2k resistor.

Comment: What does simplified mean? Are there inputs or outputs of relevance? if not you can simplify considerably.

Comment: @pipe [Falstad Circuit Simulator](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/).

Answer (score 4):

- 1k and 2k are parallel as you suggested.
- You can do wye to delta transformation for 6k, 2.5k and 2k.
- After this, one leg of the delta resistors will be in parallel with the 4.5k
- After the third step, you can use delta to wye back.
- After the fourth step, the resistor remaining in the place of 2k will be in series with the resistor you find in the first step.

There might be more simplifications. Think of **wye-delta transformations** whenever you are stuck.